# How to restrict Google Places autocomplete API by a radius within a certain longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using this code mentioned in docs
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

How should I strictly restrict results by a certain radius about a coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's code example is biasing Autocomplete results to the user's geographical location using `setBounds()`:

```
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

To actually **restrict** Autocomplete results to the given bounds, use [`strictBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area):

```
autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: true})
```

Hope this helps you.